# How to keep Chocolatey install params when doing an upgrade

Tags: windows, parameters, upgrade, chocolatey

As a reluctant windows admin I like Chocolatey a lot. I have installed some of our software with special parameters, e.g. `choco install webex --params "/ALLUSERS"`. Infortunately, when I run `choco upgrade all` those params seem to get lost, when the package actually received an upgrade. Consequently, in this case other users can no longer use webex.

Is there a way to keep those params when doing an `choco upgrade all`?

So far, I have to take care about this case when upgrading, and then do an excplicit `uninstall` and then re-install as shown above with the desired params. Suboptimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have the Chocolatey feature `useRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades` enabled. You can do this by running `choco feature enable -n='useRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades'`

See the [docs](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/configuration#general-1) for more information.